# How can I rename a field for all documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Assuming I have a collection in MongoDB with 5000 records, each containing something similar to:

```
{
"occupation":"Doctor",
"name": {
   "first":"Jimmy",
   "additional":"Smith"
}
```

Is there an easy way to rename the field "additional" to "last" in all documents? I saw the [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator in the documentation but I'm not really clear on how to specify a subfield.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

You can use:

```js
db.foo.update({}, {
    $rename: {
        "name.additional": "name.last"
    }
}, false, true);
```

Or to just update the docs which contain the property:

```js
db.foo.update({
    "name.additional": {
        $exists: true
    }
}, {
    $rename: {
        "name.additional": "name.last"
    }
}, false, true);
```

The `false, true` in the method above are: `{ upsert:false, multi:true }`. You need the `multi:true` to update **all** your records.

Or you can use the former way:

```js
remap = function (x) {
    if (x.additional) {
        db.foo.update({
            _id: x._id
        }, {
            $set: {
                "name.last": x.name.additional
            }, $unset: {
                "name.additional": 1
            }
        });
    }
}
    
db.foo.find().forEach(remap);
```

**In MongoDB 3.2 you can also use**

```js
db.students.updateMany({}, { 
    $rename: { 
        "oldname": "newname" 
    } 
})
```

The general syntax of this is

```js
db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: Just a word for if you are banging your head against the wall because nothing is mass updated: the `false, true` in the `update` method of the `$rename` version are: `{ upsert:false, multi:true }`. You need the `multi:true` to update all your records.

Comment: and if I'm getting it `upsert:true` will create field name if field name does not exists, defaults to `false`.

Comment: For some reason, this didn't work for me when I used the `"table.field" : "table.field"` syntax.  It did work when I just used the `"field" : "field"` syntax.

Comment: @Steve `name.last` is not `table.field`. If you read the question, you can see that the `name` field holds an object.

Comment: Is this working with arrays as well? Can I do:
`db.foo.update({}, {$rename:{"name.0.additional":"name.0.last"}}, false, true)`?

Comment: For future generations. this also works in form {'fieldName': 'subDocument.fieldName'}

Comment: perfect, for me I have to write as Model.collection.updateMany(filterObject, {$rename:{<oldField> : <newField>}})
I'm running mongoose version 3.2.7 may be because of versioning. Thank You

Comment: `db.parks.update({}, {$rename:{"pipe":"location"}}, false, true);` this doesnj't work for me.

Answer (score 68):

You can use the [$rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/#_S_rename) field update operator:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  { $rename: { 'name.additional': 'name.last' } },
  { multi: true }
)
```

Comment: According to the new documentation, it should look like: db.collectionName.updateMany({}, { $rename : { 'name.additional' : 'name.last' } } )

Comment: @1r3k this is old but to help others avoid confusion, no, `updateMany` is a Mongoose command, not a MongoDB command. that command won't work.

Comment: @ChumiestBucket no, this is correct. UpdateMany is a mongodb command. See here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Answer (score 15):

If ever you need to do the same thing with mongoid:

```
Model.all.rename(:old_field, :new_field)
```

**UPDATE**

There is change in the syntax in `monogoid 4.0.0`:

```
Model.all.rename(old_field: :new_field)
```

Comment: There is change in the syntax in the last monogoid (4.0.0) `Model.all.rename(old_field: :new_field)`

Comment: How can i use this option for embeded document

Answer (score 4):

Anyone could potentially use this command to rename a field from the collection (By not using any _id):

```
dbName.collectionName.update({}, {$rename:{"oldFieldName":"newFieldName"}}, false, true);
```

see [FYI](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

Answer (score 1):

I am using ,**Mongo 3.4.0**

The $rename operator updates the name of a field and has the following form:

```
{$rename: { <field1>: <newName1>, <field2>: <newName2>, ... } }
```

for e.g

```
db.getCollection('user').update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { 'fname': 'FirstName', 'lname': 'LastName' } } )
```

The new field name must differ from the existing field name. To specify a  in an embedded document, use dot notation.

This operation renames the field nmae to name for all documents in the collection:

```
db.getCollection('user').updateMany( {}, { $rename: { "add": "Address" } } )

db.getCollection('user').update({}, {$rename:{"name.first":"name.FirstName"}}, false, true);
```

In the method above  false, true are: { upsert:false, multi:true }.To update all your records, You need the multi:true.

**Rename a Field in an Embedded Document**

```
db.getCollection('user').update( { _id: 1 }, { $rename: { "name.first": "name.fname" } } )
```

use link : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: The embedding option is not working... I get this error

"cannot use the part (address of address.city) to traverse the element"

Answer (score 0):

This nodejs code just do that , as @Felix Yan mentioned former way seems to work just fine , i had some issues with other snipets hope this helps.

This will rename column "oldColumnName" to be "newColumnName" of table "documents"

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
//var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
var url = 'mongodb://myuser:mypwd@myserver.cloud.com:portNumber/databasename';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  renameDBColumn(db, function() {
    db.close();
  });

});

//
// This function should be used for renaming a field for all documents
//
var renameDBColumn = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  console.log("renaming database column of table documents");
  //use the former way:
  remap = function (x) {
    if (x.oldColumnName){
      db.collection('documents').update({_id:x._id}, {$set:{"newColumnName":x.oldColumnName}, $unset:{"oldColumnName":1}});
    }
  }

  db.collection('documents').find().forEach(remap);
  console.log("db table documents remap successfully!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoMapper, this works:

```
Access.collection.update( {}, { '$rename' => { 'location' => 'location_info' } }, :multi => true )
```