# Rename appears not to work in Mongo 2.4

Tags: mongodb

I want to rename a field from `id` to `other`, for all items in the collection. When I issue this in the console, nothing happens.

```
db.my_collection.update({}, {$rename: {"id": "other"}}, {multi:true})
```

If I then issue a

```
db.my_collection.find()
```

The fields are still as before. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works for me (Debian + Mongo 2.4.5). Could you add example documents and some info about platform?

Comment: Away from my machine now, but from memory, latest release of ubuntu and mongo. 50000000 documents, each about 100 bytes.

Comment: I expect the call to block, is that a correct assumption?

Comment: I also just tested with 2.4.4 on ubuntu and this works for me

Comment: @Joe Yes, since it is a write operation there is a lock involved. I've tested if it works on a larger collection (about 20 000 000 documents) and everything seems to be OK.

Comment: So I have to assume that my instance of mongo isn't doing what it should. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Gracias señor Dali, I'll start small and work up. I'm on the latest version, and a new OS and database install.

Comment: Hi guys. I did say what version of Mongo I was using but didn't check the documentation (stupid me assuming Ubuntu would come with a recent version). The old syntax works. I'll close this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I rename a field for all documents in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb)