# Renaming fields in every document in a MongoDB collection using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb) I gather that `upsert: false` and `multi: true` fields need to be set for this to work.

However, when I try to code this in PHP, I have a problem:

```
$conn = new Mongo("mongodb://foo:bar@localhost:27017");
$db = $conn->selectDB("someDB");

$data = array('$rename' => array(
  'nmae' => 'name'
));
$db->command(array(
  'findAndModify' => 'foo',
  'update' => $data,
  'upsert' => 'false',
  'multi' => 'true'
));
```

After running this script, only the first document with the `nmae` typo is changed to `name`; the rest still say `nmae`. The same as if I had run it without the `upsert` and `multi` options.

I also tried this:

```
$data = array('$rename' => array(
  'nmae' => 'name'
),
'upsert' => 'false',
'multi' => 'true'
);
$db->command(array(
  'findAndModify' => 'foo',
  'update' => $data
));
```

But that does the same thing.

Any way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The findAndModify query doesn't have a "multi" option:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findandmodify.php

What you probably want to use is update instead: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php

Comment: Thanks, but that still doesn't seem to work on every document the way the corresponding command does when run in MongoDB. What I have is `$db->someDB->update(array(), $data, array('$multi' => true, '$upsert' => false));` Maybe the `multi` option was never implemented in the PHP-Mongo Driver.

Comment: nvm. Didn't read the documentation closely enough. It should be `array('multiple' => true)`