# How do I rename all the fields in my database schema using Sails.js, sails-mong and Mongo DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I have a sails app using sails-mongo and mongo db ... in the Database schema I originally named on of the fields 'name', I've since named the same key in other data types 'deviceName'. I would like to rename all of the records so that the field is updated to deviceName but I'm struggling with the best way to go about doing that. I saw an NPM module called migrate ... seem like in might be promising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$rename` operator in mongodb. Here is the [mongodb docs for rename](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/)

**Update** 
There are already a great SO post regarding this. Check out [this thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `columnName` property to map a model attribute name to an existing column.  So, in your model file:

```
attributes: {
    deviceName: {
        type: 'string',
        columnName: 'name'
    }
    ...
}
```