# mongoid update not updating existing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

After research, I found this [link](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/persistence/atomic.html#rename) which shows you can update a field dynamically in mongoid:

```
Model#rename
Performs MongoDB's $rename modifier that renames a field atomically.

MONGOID 
person.rename(:bday, :dob) 

MONGODB COMMAND
collections["people"].update(   { "_id" : ... },   { "$rename" : {
"bday" : "dob" } } )
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb) stackoverflow post, when the fourth paraemeter is set to true, it should update all your records. But it is not working. When I do the following:

```
Contact.rename('apple info', 'new_info', false, true)
```

And then query mongodb:

```
db.mongoid_container_contacts.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("558c50256d6163b255060000"), "apple info" : "etretrytr", ...
```

As you can see, 'apple info' remains in the existing records. Why isn't the name of the existing records being updated?

Comment: @muistooshort I am using Mongoid 4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Contact.rename` method in Mongoid4, that method seems to have gone away in Mongoid3. If you want to rename a field in Mongoid3+, you want to call [`rename`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FContextual%2FAtomic%3Arename) on a query:

```
Contact.all.rename('apple info' => 'new_info')
```

Comment: Are you sure this is supposed to update current fields in the mongodb database? I tried it and it did not update existing fields in the database.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me. How are you checking that it didn't work?