# mongodb rename a field using condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the below query to change the field name

```
router.get("/rename", function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('Users');
    collection.update({ "Age" : "Male" }, { $rename: { "Age":"Sex" } })
});
```

The document structure is like

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55bb3b93324467d01e09c5c0"
    },
    "Sex":"Male",
    "Age": "23",
    "userId": "1014366544066103",
    "emailId":"someid"
}
```

Here I am trying to change field name **Age** to **Sex,** **if the Age field contains Male.**

But for some reason it is not changing it

I don't get any errors too

Comment: What does the document look like? Are you trying to change multiple documents and did not use `{ "multi" true }`

Comment: yes i am trying to change multiple documents, will add details on document structure to question now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rename a field for all documents in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking at a different document than the first one affected. The only problem I see here is the lack of `{ "multi": true }`:

```js
collection.update(
    { "Age" : "Male" }, 
    { "$rename": { "Age":"Sex" } },
    { "muti": true }
)
```

That should update all documents. Without it only the "first" match is affected.

Also, check your documents. The example you added already has a "Sex" field.

To safely fix this then:

```js
collection.update(
    { "Age" : "Male", "Sex": { "$exists": false } }, 
    { "$rename": { "Age":"Sex" } },
    { "muti": true }
)
```

So there is no conflict.

And you can fix ones as listed with "both" fields as "Male" with:

```js
collection.update(
    { "$where": "return this.Age = this.Sex" }, 
    { "$unset": { "Age": 1 } },
    { "muti": true }
)
```

As [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) will remove the duplicated field there.