# How to rename a document field in a MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

How is possible to rename a field in multiples documents in a MongoDB? 
I have a collections with elements like this, and I want the rename the field "**name**" by "**userName**" in all the collection

```
{
    "name"       : "luisPerez",
    "address"    : "Gaiman",
    "addressFmt" : "Gaiman, Chubut Province, Argentina",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ -65.4920111, -43.2895976  ]
    }, 
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may use [rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator to rename your fields

`db.coll.update({}, {$rename:{"name":"userName"}}, false, true)`;

```
false : upsert:false
true : multi:true
```

Comment: In pymongo, this looks like `db.coll.update_many({}, {"$rename": {"name": "userName"}})`, since `update` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

Posible duplicity with:

[How can I rename a field for all documents in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb)

Posible use $rename

```
db.collection({}, {$rename:{"name":"userName"}}, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

It is a new feature of 3.2 - 3.4 . If you have previous version, you have to pass all documents and set new field and after that unset the previous one.