# Update Embedded Document Mongo Field Name

Tags: mongodb

I went through this link: [How to rename a document field in a MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736234/how-to-rename-a-document-field-in-a-mongodb), but its not working fine for me. I've Mongo Document like below. I am using `MongoDB server version: 4.0.3`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5cb825e566135255e0bf38a4"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "svc_user",
    .....
    .....
    "status" : "A",
    "effDate" : ISODate("2012-08-24T01:46:33.000Z"),
    "department" : [ 
        {
            "deptName" : "KG",
            ....
            ....
        }, 
        ...
        ....
        .....
    ],
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I executed the below query:

```
db.employee.update({}, {$rename:{"department.deptName":"department.departmentName"}}, false, true);
```

Error:
cannot use the part (department of department.deptName) to traverse the element

Comment: For fields in embedded documents, the $rename operator can rename these fields as well as move the fields in and out of embedded documents. $rename does not work if these fields are in array elements.

please show this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/

Comment: also visite this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongo 4.2 you could run this one:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   {
      department: { $exists: true },
      "department.deptName": { $exists: true }
   },
   [{
      $set: {
         department: {
            $map: {
               input: "$department",
               in: { departmentName: "$$this.deptName" }
            }
         }
      }
   }]
)
```

I assume in 4.0.3. you have to modify the field name one-by-one with a loop in JavaScript