# Copy and rename a document field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to rename a field that all documents have in my Mongo collection. [There's already a great answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254351/how-can-i-rename-a-field-for-all-documents-in-mongodb). But instead of overwriting the current property name, I want to save my renamed property as a new field, leaving the original intact.

Imagine my documents look like this:

```
{
  "property": "Original property value"
}
```

I want to obtain this:

```
{
  "property": "Original property value",
  "property_new": "Original property value"
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  [**`$out`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "property_new": "$property"
  }},
  { "$out": "newCollection" }
])
```

It will create a new collection with the name `newCollection` just rename it with the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

You simply iterator over the collection elements on mongo shell and update each documents i.e add new attributes as `property_new` in `forEach` function as below:

```
db.st5.find().forEach(function(o) { db.st5.update({"_id":o._id}, {$set: {"property_new": o.property} } )})
```

Before updating I have insert one document in the collection `st5` as:

```
> db.st5.insert({
...   "property": "Original property value"
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.st5.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c643368b913e399ee84b4f8"), "property" : "Original property value" }
```

And then iterating over the each elements and updating as below:

```
> db.st5.find().forEach(function(o) { db.st5.update({"_id":o._id}, {$set: {"property_new": o.property} } )})
> db.st5.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c643368b913e399ee84b4f8"), "property" : "Original property value", "property_new" : "Original property value" }
>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.